# WARNING: could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Stale file handle

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes-ingress, glusterfs

I am running postgres in Kubernetes cluster and seeing this warning.

What kind of problem/warning it is? How can I fix this?

Here is full log on container startup:

```
 .. PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
 .. UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 (Debian 13.0-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
... UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
... UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
... UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
... UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-02 10:16:05 UTC
... UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
... UTC [28] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Stale file handle
```

Here the volume is mounted by glusterfs from three replica

Comment: the problem seems like due to glusterfs: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1609210

Answer (score 3):

If that problem occurs only occasionally, it can be a sign of I/O overload, but is harmless as such.

If you get that message all the time, something is wrong with your statistics collector, and you should find and fix the problem, because statistics are important for the health of your database (autovacuum).

Comment: how to fix this? more info about this problem?
Yes, i am getting it occasionally. Log is full with this warning

Comment: Hard to say from here. Could be [network problems](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/stale-statistics-cause-table-bloat/), could be I/O problems.

Comment: I have a similar problem as well and its nothing to do with I/O problems

Comment: @user352290 Sure, [there are other causes](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/stale-statistics-cause-table-bloat/).

Answer (score 0):

Update: This problem comes from gluserfs and issue is not yet resolved by glusterfs https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/issues/502